# Remove content editor name when page has been published

Tags: office-365, content-editor-web-part

I have a content editor webpart in Office 365.  When I publish the page the content editor name is still there. How can I remove this?

Comment: You mean the title?

Comment: yeah I guess it is the title

Comment: Everything is configurable in the webpart properties that open on the right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your Web Part Properties and set Chrome equal None.

[image]

**That's all about hiding web part title.**